# open a secure socket on the server side

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I have a server application that opens a socket and then listens to any connections being made on that socket.

```
public Server(){
    try {
        ServerSocket sSocket = new ServerSocket(nPort);
        System.out.println("Server started at: " + new Date());
        System.out.println("===============================================\n");

        //Loop that runs server functions
        while(true) {
            //Wait for a client to connect
            Socket socket = sSocket.accept();
            socket.setSoTimeout(30000);
            //Create a new custom thread to handle the connection
            ClientThread cT = new ClientThread(socket, nPort);
            //Start the thread!
            new Thread(cT).start();  
        }
    } 
    catch(IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Whenever new connection attempted, a new thread is started using the `ClientThread` class. The `ClientThread` class has a run method that does all the things need to be done (read input, send respons etc.)

```
public class ClientThread implements Runnable{
private Socket threadSocket;
private int nPort = 0, maxCon = 2;

//This constructor will be passed the socket
public ClientThread_v3(Socket socket, int port){
    threadSocket = socket;
    nPort = port;
}

public void run(){
    System.out.println("New connection at " + new Date() + "\n");
    try {
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream (threadSocket.getInputStream());
        out = new DataOutputStream (threadSocket.getOutputStream());                  
        while (running){ 
            // do some stuff ....

            // go to sleep
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();} 
    catch (InterruptedException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    finally {
        try {
            threadSocket.close();
            System.out.println("Connection closed.\n");
        } catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
}}
```

My question is how do i make the socket connection secure? how do i open a secure connection? 
I don't want to use any HTTP packages for that matter, want to keep it as a socket connection.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You may start from [SSLSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html). Despite the name it supports TLS. Be sure to properly configure the socket before using it.

Comment: What do you mean by properly configuring the socket? Is there any special configurations?

Comment: Yes, for example: If the client needs to be authenticated, the enabled ciphers. Eventually the certificates.  See [SSLParameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLParameters.html) and if you are planning to use this in production environments consider reading the [TLS 1.2 RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246) and proper guidelines.

Comment: Does this authentication is additional  to the one that's inside the GET request?

Comment: It's the TLS authentication, the reverse of the usual server authentication. Usually made through the use of certificates.

Comment: ok thank you. i'll dig into that.